# alternate proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

I was reading over my notes from complex analysis and saw the fundamental theorem of algebra which states that:

> A polynomial of positive degree over a field $\mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers has a root in $\mathbb{C}.$

Now, I've noticed that the proof of this requires the use of (complex) analysis. I'm wondering whether anyone knows any proofs of this outside the realm of (complex) analysis?

Comment: The [wiki page](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) on the theorem lists some proofs.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10535/ways-to-prove-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra

Comment: There are lots of proofs for this one.  I suspect if someone compiled a list of theorems ranked by the number of published proofs, this one would rank pretty high.  But not as high as the Pythagorean theorem or the law of quadratic reciprocity.

Answer (score 0):

this is only a line of argument, and is only for a special case. i wonder if it can be tightened up?

let the coefficients of $p(z) = a_0+a_1z+\dots+a_mz^m$ be Gaussian integers $\in \mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z}$ and $a_0=1$.

then by the division algorithm we may find a non-terminating series $q(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} b_jz^j$ (with $b_0=1$) such that *formally* $p(z)q(z) = 1$. since the coefficients of $q(z)$ are integers its radius of convergence cannot exceed unity. i want to deduce that $q$ must have a pole in the closed unit disc, and that therefore $p$ must have a root there.